# Can session/cookie request token be sent via url?

Tags: authentication

What are the security concerns if a session token is sent via url over https?

After authentication a rest api sends a unique session token that is used to validate subsequent requests. It is typically sent via https POST. Is there a security concern for sending the token in a url parameter via GET?

Logging complete url requests could be a potential security concern.

Comment: *If* the application is following all of the best practices (using TLS exclusively, rotating session IDs periodically and on all privilege level changes, etc., etc...), then including session IDs as a request parameter rather than cookies is mostly a usability issue rather than a security issue.  (A user's session might be unexpectedly invalidated due to use of the back button, for example.)  However, third party scripts might be able to get the current URI, leaving a narrow window for session hijacking that HttpOnly on cookies avoid.  (POST and GET provide the same lack of security here.)

Comment: Yes, rotating session ids and upgraded servers and require the latest TLS. Good point on third party scripts. I wonder if any header can be set as httponly or if it has to be an actual "cookie"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TLS will make sure it is encrypted in transit, so it will be protected against MITM attacks. But there are other reasons why this is a bad idea.

The token will be exposed in a lot of places. Server logs is a big issue, as you mention. Suddenly you will have to treat all your logs from where you terminate TLS and downstreams as security critical. Another issue is having the token exposed in the users browsing history, or even worse if they share an URL on social media. For an API that might be less of a issue, but if I had a penny for every time I have seen people expose authentication tokens when posting questions in support forums...

I understand why this might be a tempting design, but I strongly recommend that you just use a cookie or an Authorization header instead.